# Google play internal beta track not showing update after 14hrs

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

We released an internal version on google play's beta channel. But our testers still see the old version. While google play console says all 96 testers have that build (3.10.1) available.

[image]

They still see the old version (3.9.9) with their beta test accounts
[image]

Is there any new step required, because google doesn't give any warning or notice and its been 14hours+.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? Or did it resolve itself with time? For us its been already well over a week...

Comment: How long did it take before it resolved for you?